# XSD. Incorrect type definition

Tags: xml, xsd

I wrote a XML type definition, but it is not correct. Where my mistake? How can I rewrite it?

```
  <xs:complexType name="resourceKeyName">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:maxLength value="30"/>
        <xs:minLength value="5"/>
        <xs:pattern value="^ref-"/>
      </xs:restriction>   
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
```

===================================

**update**

I rewrote my code like this:

```
<xs:complexType name="_inner">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>  

  <xs:complexType name="resourceKeyName">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:restriction base="_inner">
        <xs:maxLength value="30"/>
        <xs:minLength value="5"/>
        <xs:pattern value="^ref-"/>     
      </xs:restriction>   
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
```

The code is correct now, but I don't like such a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not:

```
<xs:simpleType name="resourceKeyName">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:maxLength value="30" />
        <xs:minLength value="5" />
        <xs:pattern value="^ref-" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Do you want to have type which has nested elements, or just text content? If you want text - you should create `xs:simpleType`.